# IntelliJ Remove Unwanted Modules/Packages from Packages View

Tags: intellij-idea

I am potentially fat fingering a hot key in IntelliJ and cannot figure out how to restore the default Packages View in the Projects Tool Window.  My packages view will change from the default view:

```
io.xxx.yyy
   MyClass.java
```

to

```
io
   com.android.tools.idea.observable.core
   cucumber.cucumberexpressions
   flutter
   grpc 
   xxx.yyy  (the package I am working on)
   .... and a lot of other modules/packages I do not want to see
```

Does anyone know the setting (or the hotkey) that I need to reset to get back to the default packages view - and remove all the excess modules, libraries, SDKs from the view?  If you also know what HotKey I may be fat fingering so I can disable it - that would be awesome as well.

I have found some information in the [IntelliJ Manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html?section=Windows%20or%20Linux#views) - it states that in the Packages View it does not display Modules, SDKs, and Libraries by default...  which is awesome and what I want...  I just need to figure out how to get back to this default view.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot from Project Tool window? Looks like you switched from "Project" to "Packages".

Answer (score 0):

Per Jetbrains support - [this is a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248797).  The workaround that is working for me is to disable the Kotlin plug in (Files -> Settings -> Plugins)...  The support person stated that the bug should be fixed in 2021.1 ...  Attaching screenshot of some of the packages that show up - they all appear to be empty.

[Screenshot of Package View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgvNm.png)